# I do not understand why the qualifier static applied to x here?

Tags: c, pointers, qualifiers

In case of declaration;

```
const int *p;
```

specifier `const` is applied to `int` i.e, the object `p` points to.
while regarding the statement(*JUNE 1998, EMBEDDED SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING*);

> Some declaration specifiers do not contribute to the type of the declarator-id.Rather, they specify other semantic information that applies directly to the declarator-id. For example, in:

```
static unsigned long int *x[N];
```

> the keyword `static` does not apply to the `unsigned long int` objects that the pointers in `x` point to. Rather, it applies to `x` itself:

```
 ---------------------------   
/    \                    / \ 
static unsigned long int * x [N];
```

> This declares that `x` is a ***static object*** of type *“array of N elements of pointer to unsigned long int.”*

I do not understand why `static` applied to `x`?

Comment: Can you imagine to apply `static` to `unsigned long int*` but not to `x`? If answer is "no" then order doesn't matter because `static` and `const` are two different things. In the case of `const` it's different: `const int* p` is not the same as `int* const p`.

Comment: What would you expect it to be applied to?

Comment: The variable `x` has array type (this is the `unsigned long *[n]` part, more precisely it is an array of `n` pointers to unsigned long. However `static` has nothing to do with types: it denotes the *storage class* of `x` (others are `extern`, `auto` and `register`). You may want to read other books if you find this one unclear (it seems unclear to me too), see eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @AlexandreC. Yes you are right. Sorry for asking such a stupid question.

Comment: @AlexandreC.; Ya. That's why I was confused. But now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static doesn't make sense to apply to the type.   static applies to the storage location / visibility of x  ( depending where its declared )

Answer (score 1):

Storage-class specifiers and type qualifiers are completely different things. The type qualifier (`const`, `volatile`, or `restrict`) is part of the type, whereas storage-class specifiers (`typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `auto`, or `register`) are part of the declaration.

If you're referring to C99, see *6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers* and *6.7.3 Type qualifiers*.